# Create dynamic web hook for Jira, connect Spring boot

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am attempting to register a web hook to my Jira cloud instance and I am following their [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-connect-spring-boot/src/master/) but I have not been able to make it work.

Specifically the section: `Making API requests to the product as the add-on`:

```
atlassianHostRestClients.authenticatedAsAddon(AddonAuthenticationType.OAUTH2).getForObject("/rest/api/example", Void.class);
```

My issue is when I run it I get an error:

> 401 Unauthorized: "{"message":"Client must be authenticated to access this >resource.","status-code":401}"

Now, I know I am not authenticated, but `atlassianHostRestClients` object, which according to their documentation:

> atlassian-connect-spring-boot will automatically sign requests from your add-on to an >installed host product with JSON Web Tokens. To make a request, just autowire an > AtlassianHostRestClients object into your class.

So, anyone has experience with this that could help?

Answer (score 0):

I do this using [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) and have a generic function in my class `JiraApiHelpers.kt`:

```
class JiraApiHelpers(
    internal val atlassianRestClient: AtlassianHostRestClients
) {
    fun <T: Any>getRequest(url: String, host: AtlassianHost, clazz: KClass<T>): T {
        return atlassianRestClient.authenticatedAsAddon(host).getForObject(url, clazz.java)
            ?: throw Exceptions.InvalidJiraApiRequestException(url, host)
    }
}
```

This let me format the returned object to given data class:

```
val issueData = jiraApiHelpers.getRequest(urlField, hostUser.host, JiraIssueData::class)
```

Here `hostUser` origins from my controller which is called by the webhook:

```
@PostMapping("/webhook")
fun calculateEstimatedEndTime(
    @RequestBody issueEvent: JiraIssueEvent,
    @AuthenticationPrincipal hostUser: AtlassianHostUser
```

This is implemented in a connect-app where the webhook is defined within the app in `atlassian-connect.json`:

```
"webhooks": [
  {
    "event": "jira:issue_updated",
    "url": "/webhook",
    "excludeBody": false
  }
]
```

To test your scenario I removed `host` from my call to Jira API and it worked as expected:

```
atlassianRestClient.authenticatedAsAddon().getForObject(url, clazz.java)
```

I see in the documentation you linked to, that the use of `AddonAuthenticationType.OAUTH2` is limited to [Connect-on-Forge](https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/forge/build-a-connect-on-forge-app/) apps. Maybe that is why you get 401.